# Jupyter notebook not opening on windows

Tags: windows, installation, jupyter-notebook

I can't open Jupiter notebook through my command line in windows. It shows error 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Comment: Dear Rupal, this problem of yours could be caused by several reasons. One possibility is that your Python is installed without a conda environment. In case you have an Anaconda installaled, a second cause could be due to the type of the installation you chose during Anaconda installation. A third cause could be a problem of the Path of your Windows-System. Please check each one of these cases is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try on cmd the following:
`py -m notebook`

Answer (score 0):

These problems can occur. If you have installed python correctly, first install jupyter
in command promt by

**pip install jupyter**

or in Anaconda Promt, if you installed via Anaconda

then even , its not opening, try running **cmd by administrator** then type

**jupyter notebook**